# useEffect() triggers components re-render in one function but not in the other one. Both function DO change state. What am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

It must be something really silly I do wrong here. useEffect() works perfectly with MonthModificatorHandler but not re-render when using dayClick.  When dayclick was only adding days re-render worked properly. After adding logic to remove days already in state re-rendering stopped. I can call saveChanges and loadTimeline to fix functionality but if you click few days in a row asynchronous call leads to unexpected results. Thanks for your time.

```
export default function DatePicker(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [monthModificator, setMonthModificator] = React.useState(0);
    const [monthMatrix, setMonthMatrix] = React.useState([]);
    const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = React.useState([]);

    const MonthModificatorHandler = value => {
        setMonthModificator(monthModificator + value);
    };

    const dayClick = day => {
        let data = selectedDates;
        let addDay = true;
        if (data.length === 0) {
            data.push(day);
        } else {
            data.map((date, index) => {
                if (day.equals(date)) {
                    data.splice(index, 1);
                    addDay = false;
                }
            });
            if (addDay) {
                data.push(day);
            }
        }
        setSelectedDates(data);
       // saveChanges();
       // loadTimeline();
    };

    let now = DateTime.local().plus({ months: monthModificator });

    let firstDayOfFirstWeek = now.startOf("month").startOf("week");

    let lastDayOfLasttWeek = now.endOf("month").endOf("week");

    let monthToDisplay = Interval.fromDateTimes(
        firstDayOfFirstWeek,
        lastDayOfLasttWeek
    );

    function loadTimeline() {
        axios.get(`/timeline`).then(response => {
            let selectedDays = [];

            response.data.map(date => {
                selectedDays.push(DateTime.fromISO(date));
            });

            setSelectedDates(selectedDays);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let load = true;
        if (load) {
            loadTimeline();
            load = false;
        }
        var matrix = [];

        for (let v = 0; v < monthToDisplay.length("day"); v++) {
            matrix.push(firstDayOfFirstWeek.plus({ day: v }));
        }

        setMonthMatrix(matrix);
    }, [selectedDates, monthModificator]);

 
    function saveChanges() {
        let arrayOfDataObjects = selectedDates;

        let arrayOfDataStrings = arrayOfDataObjects.map(singleDataObject => {
            return (
                "," +
                JSON.stringify(singleDataObject.toISODate()).replaceAll('"', "") // extra quotes removed
            );
        });

        axios.post(`/timeline`, {
            timeline: arrayOfDataStrings
        });
    }

    return (
        <Grid container justify="space-around">
            <Button onClick={() => MonthModificatorHandler(1)}>+</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => MonthModificatorHandler(-1)}>-</Button>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                {monthMatrix.map((day, index) => {
                    let color = "secondary";
                    selectedDates.map(workingDay => {
                        if (day.equals(workingDay)) {
                            color = "primary";
                        }
                    });

                    return (
                        <Button
                            color={color}
                            variant="contained"
                            onClick={() => dayClick(day)}
                            className={classes.days}
                            key={index}
                        >
                            {day.day}
                        </Button>
                    );
                })}
            </Card>
            <Button onClick={() => saveChanges()}>Save Changes</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => loadTimeline()}>Update Changes</Button>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you compute new state from previous state. It should be done with callback https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates
Try something like

```js
const dayClick = day => setSelectedDates((_data) => {
        let data =[..._data];
        let addDay = true;
        if (data.length === 0) {
            data.push(day);
        } else {
            data.map((date, index) => {
                if (day.equals(date)) {
                    data.splice(index, 1);
                    addDay = false;
                }
            });
            if (addDay) {
                data.push(day);
            }
        }
       return data
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It should work but now is not updating state. Function triggers return the correct value (console.log it) but not updating state. Puzzling

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Kostya Tresko, thank you. On top of that, another mistake was in the hook itself. The way I loaded data caused re rending loop.

```
if (load) {
loadTimeline();
load = false;
}
```

DO NOT DO THAT